# How to stop audio by clicking button and jumped to other activity (layout)

Tags: android

on one activity an audio is being played.
now i want to click on a button so that audio should stopped and also an other activity opened using intent.
i used  .stop() to stop audio. but when i click on button, a message is shown `unfortunately application has stopped`, and my application is closed, what to do of it???

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button enterbutton;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaPlayer mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_act);
            mPlayer.start();

    enterbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_enter1);
    enterbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mPlayer.stop();
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Select_destination.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_act);
```

To

```
mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_act);
```

As it reinit the  MediaPlayer .

Answer (score 2):

You have already make a Global varible for media player and also make a second time after oncreate() method.. So change it by:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_act);
```

to

```
mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_act);
```